# Pycharm highlights code import tensorflow.compat.v1

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I've got code that does `import tensorflow.compat.v1`. Import is going with no errors but PyCharm highlighted this code and says No module named compat. My tensorflow version is 2.4.1
[image]

Why does PyCharm say that there's no module compat but the program executes correctly?
Why doesn't the program fails on this line while executing?

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you.

Comment: Just one line: `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`. Pycharm says No module named compat. But actually tjis line works. I think it's a little Pycharm bug though

Comment: Can you share version details of pycharm and python?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the obvious question. Python is 3.6.3. Pycharm is 2017.3 Community. Tensorflow is 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess rewriting it as import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf    would work

Answer (score 0):

Update TF-GPU to 2.6+, then problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).